# jQuery .each function runs over and ajax response showing later

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using facebook api to post message on list of facebook pages using jquery .each function. The problem is that .each function runs quickly and send pages ids to my ajax function. And before the response of ajax request .each function send next page id to ajax function and in the end facebook api post message on last page id in queue. and number of post messages is the length of page id in queue.
For Ex. i have 3 page id in

```
<select>
<option>page1 id|AccessToken></option>
<option>page2 id|AccessToken></option>
<option>page3 id|AccessToken></option>
</select>
```

Jquery .each function send all pageID to ajax function and facebook api post 3 message on last page3 id. because i have three page id in queue therefor facebook api post three message on last page3 id.

**I need to post message on each page ID, after ajax response from facebook api, then .each function send 2nd page request to facebook api and so on.**

I used the following code.

> **Java Script Code**

```
function submitPost()}{
  $('#users input:checkbox').each(function () {
        var a = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");        
        if (a != ""){    
          postToPage(a)    // a = PageId|AccessToken <option>PageId|AccessToken</option>
        } 
  });
}
function postToPage(c) {
    dataSeprator = c.split("|");
    d = dataSeprator[0];
    my_message = $('#txtmsg').val();
    url = $('#txturl').val();
    title = $('#txttitle').val();
    desc = $('#txtdesc').val();
    picUrl = 'facebook.png';
    FB.api('/' + d, { fields: 'access_token'}, function (b) {
        if (dataSeprator[1].length > 0) {
            FB.api('/' + d + '/feed', 'post', {
                message: my_message,
                link: url,
                name: title,
                picture: picUrl,
                description: desc,
                access_token: dataSeprator[1]
            }, function (a) {
                if (!a || a.error) {
                    alert('Error occured')
                } else {
                    alert('Message Posted Successfully.')
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for asynchronous calls, as you're doing here, are designed to not block any other code that you're running. So the each loop will loop regardless of a response. So your solution is a different pattern.

First save your jQuery objects in an array

```
var user_checkboxes = [];
user_checkboxes = $('#users input:checkbox');
```

And then only submit the user at index 0 first.

```
function submitPost(){
    if(user_checkboxes.length === 0) return;
    var user = user_checkboxes[0];
    var a = (user.is(':checked')) ? user.val() : "");        
    if (a != ""){    
      postToPage(a)    // a = PageId|AccessToken <option>PageId|AccessToken</option>
    }
}
```

In your response from the Ajax call you can do this

```
FB.api('/' + d, { fields: 'access_token'}, function (b) {
    if (dataSeprator[1].length > 0) {
        FB.api('/' + d + '/feed', 'post', {
            message: my_message,
            link: url,
            name: title,
            picture: picUrl,
            description: desc,
            access_token: dataSeprator[1]
        }, function (a) {
            if (!a || a.error) {
                alert('Error occured')
            } else {
                //success

                //remove from array
                user_checkboxes.splice(0,1);

                //submit the next one, now at 0
                submitPost();
            }
        })
    }
})
```

This will ensure that your code won't attempt to send another request until the first one was completed. It will stop when your array of objects is empty.

Comment: owsum solution. thats what i need. Thank you